# How can I have a checkbox as selected in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have some items to be selected,they are checkboxes with their certain titles in a table. I want to onclick on an item(I mean each "td") then the function do its job but besides I want the checkbox of that selected "td" t be checked. How can I do it with javascript?

note:I am learning javascript so please don't answer with a jquery solution.
the code below is an example of each items

```
<td id="1" onclick="chb('1')" ><input  type="checkbox" />title</td>
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and add a [mcve] to your question

Comment: What have you tried so far and have you done any research? If not then do some research and make some attempts. That would be the key to "learning" rather than coming here to copy/paste. You won't learn from that.

Answer (score 5):

This is pure JS to select a check box. You need to give your check box an Id (for example 'check1') and run the below code inside the function you call in the click event.

```
document.getElementById("check1").checked = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I didn't understand what you told. But i think you want the checkbox to be checked already. Then use `checked` in `<input>` Like this : `<input type="checkbox" checked>`
or You can use `document.getElementById("check1").checked = true;`